# Improving the resolution quality of the extracted plots to a word document

Tags: r

I am working in an  R Markdown file. All the codes are run properly and the plot is generated and managed to knit it to word document but the resolution is so poor. I found a code to improve the resolution and tried it but did not work. Any way to help to improve the resolution of the extracted plot, please.

Details:

```r
library (tidyverse)
library (readxl)
```

Data called SR_STATS

```r
SR_STATS <- read_excel('E:\\MY PROJECTS\\STRESS RADIOGRAPHS\\SR_STATS.xlsx')

PMID    Year    Ligament    Time_Period
3958018 1986    ACL Jan 1983 – Dec 1992
3685366 1987    ACL Jan 1983 – Dec 1992
2229106 1990    ACL Jan 1983 – Dec 1992
2002074 1991    ACL Jan 1983 – Dec 1992

FINALSR <- SR_STATS
FINALSR$Ligament <- factor(FINALSR$Ligament,
                         levels = c("Multiligament","Valgus","Varus","PCL","ACL"))

ggplot(data = FINALSR) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Time_Period, fill = Ligament))
```

The plot is generated and I knitted it to a word document. But the resolution is poor. I searched how to get better resolution image and found this code

```r
tiff("SR.tiff", units="in", width=5, height=5, res=300)
ggplot(data = FINALSR) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Time_Period, fill = Ligament))
dev.off ()
```

But it gives me this error message

```
Error in dev.off() : cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)
```

I tried

```r
while (!is.null(dev.list()))  dev.off()
```

and

```r
dev.set(dev.next())
```

Comment: Try `ggsave`: `ggplot(data = FINALSR) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = Time_Period, fill = Ligament))
ggsave("SR.png", dpi = 300)`

Comment: Thanks a million. This has worked and the image is very good resolution.